# How do I return the average customer balance with dollar sign and commas removed?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, each representing a customer. Some have a balance value, but not all do. I'm trying to use .reduce to find the average, but first I need to convert the balance values into numbers with extra characters removed, and I need to find which customer objects include a balance object.

Below is what I have so far, but it is not being recognized as the average customer balance:

```js
var averageBalance = function(array) {

    let sum = _.reduce(customers, function(total, current, index, array) {
        if (current.hasOwnProperty(balance) === true) {
        return  total += current.balance.replace(/[$,]/g, '');
        }
    }, 0);

    return sum / customers.length;
};
```

Comment: Please share the sample json payload

Comment: Wow, I've seen this three times today! No need to compare a boolean to a boolean when your boolean is already a boolean because your if-statement checks for a truthy value that's coerced to a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
function average(arr){
  var x = 0;
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    x += clean(arr[i]);
  }
  return(x / arr.length);
}
function clean(num){
  return(Number(num.toString().replace(/\$/g,"").replace("K",",000").replace("M",",000,000").replace("B",",000,000,000").replace(/,/g,"")));
}
function print(txt){
  document.write("<p>" + txt + "</p>");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="print(average(document.getElementById('list').value.split('|')));">Calc</button>
<input id="list"/>
<p>Use the bar <code>|</code> as a separator. You can use K, M, and B for Thousand, Million, and Billion, but only use one per value and only one time per value. Commas are supported, as they are ignored. Dollar signs are also removed.</p>
<p>This program calculates the average money listed.</p>
```

Comment: 3,5K output is 35000 but should be 3500.

Comment: Lemme fix it...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a rough idea of what you could do to parse and format your input string. It's hard to tell if it will works for each of your cases without more sample data.

```js
const calc = e => {
  let values = e.target.previousElementSibling.value.replace(/[$\s]/g, "").replace(/(,\d{1,2}){0,3}[KMB]/g, pad).split("|").map(nb => parseFloat(nb.replace(",", "")));
  let avg = values.reduce((x, y) => (x + y)) / values.length;

  console.log("Formated values", values);
  console.log("Average", avg);
}

const pad = (m, o) => (o || "").replace(",", "").padEnd((letters.indexOf(m.slice(-1)) + 1) * 3, "0");

const letters = ["K", "M", "B"];
document.getElementById("calc").addEventListener("click", calc);
```

```html
<input type="text" value="3,5K$|4,000 $|4 K|4500| 7,66M">
<input type="button" value="calc average" id="calc">
```